# PagesIndex - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

No matter how I flip this script around it still gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` message when I debug (The program runs fine if I don't debug, but every time I debug I get this message, why is that?)

```
public string GetTemplate(int pageId)
{
    string template = "";

    PagesIndex qq = new PagesIndex();
    qq = (from cc in db.PagesIndexes where cc.Id == pageId select cc).SingleOrDefault();

    if (qq.Template == null) //Here on  qq.Template - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    {
        template = "_Layout";
    }
    else
    {
        template = qq.Template;
    }
    return template;
}
```

Hope you can change my mood :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `qq` resulting from LINQ is null.
Try this

```
public string GetTemplate(int pageId)
{
    string template = "";
    PagesIndex qq = new PagesIndex();
    qq = (from cc in db.PagesIndexes where cc.Id == pageId select cc).SingleOrDefault();

    if (qq == null || qq.Template == null)
        template = "_Layout";
    }
    else
    {
        template = qq.Template;
    }
    return template;
}
```

or shortly:

```
public string GetTemplate(int pageId)
{
    PagesIndex qq = db.PagesIndexes
                      .Where(p => p.Id == pageId)
                      .SingleOrDefault();
    return qq == null || qq.Template == null ?
           "_Layout" :
           qq.Template;
}
```

Comment: Oh thats why! It makes complete sense! Why diddnt i see that. I have bin codeing i think! Thanks :)

Comment: @BjarkeCK, we've all done this one, and we'll spent some time not noticing it, again.

Answer (score 3):

The line that gives the error can only throw a `NullReferenceException` if qq is `null`. That happens if the row is not found on the line before. I guess that you thought `qq` could never be null because you assigned a non-null value to it. However the line afterwards overwrites this value with null if the row is not found.

```
PagesIndex qq = new PagesIndex();  // Pointless and misleading assignment!
qq = (from cc in db.PagesIndexes where cc.Id == pageId select cc).SingleOrDefault();
```

You could do it like this instead, using the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
public string GetTemplate(int pageId)
{
    return db.PagesIndexes
             .Where(p => p.Id == pageId)
             .Select(p => p.Template)
             .SingleOrDefault() ?? "_Layout";
}
```

Comment: Dont quit understand :( issnt PagesIndex qq = new PagesIndex(); my object?

Comment: @BjarkeCK: yes, but on next line you reassign it using `qq = (from cc ...`

Comment: @BjarkeCK: Your object comes from the call to `Single`. It is created from data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suspicion. When you debug you're using an instance of the database that doesn't have any data (or any matching data) in the PagesIndexes table.  That means that `qq` will be null as a result of the query (the Default part of SingleOrDefault).  You can confirm this by examining the connection string to make sure it's going against the DB you expect and inspecting that DB to make sure that it has the data you expect to be there.  You should also be checking if `qq` is null before you use it.

```
 if (qq == null || qq.Template == null)
 {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be catching the exception somewhere in your code and that's why your not seeing it. Your LINQ statement is not returning a result. Check qq for null not qq.Templates.

`if(qq != null)
{
  if (qq.Templates != null)...
}`